# OpenGL 2D moving relation

Tags: c, opengl, methods

I have the two methods hich are doing the same thing. Now I am wondering what is their differences and which one can perform faster.
Here are the methods:
1th Method

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f( 0, 0); glVertex2f( x, y); 
    glTexCoord2f( 1, 0); glVertex2f( x+texWidth, y); 
    glTexCoord2f( 1, 1); glVertex2f( x+texWidth, y+texHeight);
    glTexCoord2f( 0, 1); glVertex2f( x, y+texHeight);
glEnd(); 
x++; y++;
```

2th Method

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f( 0, 0); glVertex2f( 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f( 1, 0); glVertex2f( 1.0f, 0.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f( 1, 1); glVertex2f( 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f( 0, 1); glVertex2f( 0.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();

x++; y++;
```

Comment: The two methods aren't the same, you would need `glScalef(texWidth, texHeight, 1.0f)` as well as `glTranslatef`.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding performance, you are using immediate mode, which is slow anyway (its the "old" way of doing things; unfortunately most OpenGL tutorials on the web are hopelessly outdated). Use buffers (gpu-side) like VBOs and VAOs if you really care about performance.

A nice modern tutorial is http://open.gl/ which introduces VBOs here: http://open.gl/drawing

Answer (score 0):

The second method is alot faster, because it is translating the whole matrix, and doesn't do many calculations as it does in method one.

Comment: These particular operations probably run as fast or faster on the CPU as the GPU, and almost certainly are faster than adjusting the matrix, so I'd say Method #1 probably is significantly faster.

Comment: @user2442604: Only in this particular case. As soon as you're drawing more than 8 triangles, it's slower. But you shouldn't use the immediate mode (glBegin, glVertex, glEnd) in the first place. Use vertex arrays.

Comment: Yes. Use newer version of OpenGL to not "draw" on the CPU, but with the GPU.

Answer (score -1):

The second method is a lot faster, because it translates the whole QUAD matrix with less calculations.